# How to simplify $(x^{1/y})^y$?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I would like Mathematica to be able to simplify the expression $\left(x^{1/y}\right)^y$ to $x$. However, running

```
Simplify[(x^(1/y))^y]
```

does not accomplish the desired simplification. I have tried including assumptions that $y$ is both real and non-zero in order to avoid any potential pathological cases, but neither seem to do the trick. Are there additional assumptions required in order to get this to work?

Comment: `PowerExpand[(x^(1/y))^y]` does what you want.  Assumes everything is real and positive.  Assumptions would do the trick too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably meant:

```
Simplify[(x^(1/y))^y]
```

> (x^(1/y))^y

which still doesn't simplify without assumptions. You can provide assumptions:

```
Simplify[(x^(1/y))^y, Assumptions->x>0 && y>0]
```

> x

or you can use [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand):

```
PowerExpand[(x^(1/y))^y]
```

> x

Alternatively, you can give [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand) the option `Assumptions->True` to find out under what conditions the above expansion is valid:

```
PowerExpand[(x^(1/y))^y, Assumptions->True]
```

> E^(2 I π y Floor[1/2 - Im[Log[x]/y]/(2 π)]) x

Comment: Thanks! This works, but I don't understand why $x$ has to be positive. Naively taking the case $x=-1$, $y=2$ doesn't seem to give any problem, and I can't think of any situation with negative $x$ that would give the problem.

Comment: @HenryShackleton Try $x=-1$ and $y=1/2$ Basically, if $y$ is not an integer, than problems arise.

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification! Including the assumption that $y$ is an integer is also sufficient for the simplification to go through.